# app.config appSettings File Attribute absolute path

Tags: app-config

In my App.config file I'm trying to reference a file not located in the project, I've read that an absolute path should work.  However, I can't get it to work.

my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<configuration>
    ...
    <appSettings file="C:/configs/Secrets.config" />
</configuration>
```

Then in the referenced file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
   <add key="Username" value="user" />
   <add key="Password" value="password" />
</appSettings>
```

However, when I run my project the appSettings has no values attached to it.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hidden extensions, the filename was actually Sectrets.config.txt because I didn't save it as a config file